# question about equivalent metric and compactness

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $(X,d_1)$ and $(X,d_2)$ be two metrics spaces with different metrics. Assume that the two metrics are [equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics). I am wondering how do Heine-Borel property and compactness relate to the equivalence of metrics.

For example, in $\mathbb R^n$ all norms are equivalent and $[a,b]^n$ is compact under the Euclidean metric, is $[a,b]^n$ also compact under $L_{\infty}$ norm or other $L_p$?
In general, what are some of the important properties preserved by equivalent metrics?

Answer (score 2):

Equivalent metrics induce the same topology. So they share all topological properties ( i.e. properties that can be defined in terms of open sets). Compactness, separability, second countability etc are examples of such properties.